# How to slow the zoom transition speed in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, zoom

I'd like to slow the speed of the zoom transition in Leaflet, but I haven't figured out how.

I'm using `map.setView()` a few times to change the zoom level.

---

I've tried the solution suggested here:
[Setting a slower zoom speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127440/setting-a-slower-zoom-speed)

Which is to increase the transition time in CSS for

```
.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-animated {
    transition: 2s;
}
```

But, it doesn't seem to work. It starts to slow down, but then just jumps to the zoom level, so it doesn't look smooth at all.

---

The pan animation, and duration works great.

I've tried all these options:

```
map.setView([lat, long], 14, {
    pan: {
        animate: true,
        duration: 1.5
    },
    zoom: {
        animate: true
    }
});
```

and

```
var map = L.map("map", {
    center: [45.2403, -123.8512],
    zoom: 12,
    fadeAnimation: true,
    zoomAnimation: true
});
```

But nothing seems to slow or smooth the zoom transition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But, it doesn't seem to work. It starts to slow down, but then just jumps to the zoom level

That's because of this one line of code here, with a hard-coded duration:

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/release-v1.0.3/src/map/Map.js#L1573

> ```
> setTimeout(L.bind(this._onZoomTransitionEnd, this), 250);
> ```

Ideally, the zoom animations in Leaflet 1.x would be defined by the CSS transform. However, [problems with cross-browser compatibility](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3689) made necessary to hard-code that timeout.

You could overload the private `_animateZoom` by doing something like `L.Map.prototype._animateZoom = function (center, zoom, startAnim, noUpdate) { ... }`, doing an ugly copy-paste of the original but changing the duration there. That, however, is a very very ugly hack and totally not recommended.

Comment: Ivan: are you telling me that monkey patching private methods is not recommended?

Answer (score 13):

Your `map.flyTo()` has the options malformed, you want

```
map.flyTo([lat, long], 14, {
        animate: true,
        duration: 1.5
});
```

See [Doc's pan-options](https://leafletjs.com/reference#pan-options).
The same parameters will work fine also  with  `panTo()`  and `setView()` methods.

Answer (score 7):

After looking closer at the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-methods-for-modifying-map-state), I found it's better to use:

```
flyTo(<LatLng> latlng, <Number> zoom?, 
    <Zoom/pan options> options?
)
```

Instead of:

```
setView(<LatLng> center, <Number> zoom?,
    <Zoom/pan options> options?
)
```

At least for my purpose. It slows the zoom down, and appears a bit more smooth. However, it'd be nice to have more control over the zoom speed, but this is good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

With ReactLeaflet v2 this worked for me:

```
    createLeafletElement() {
        if (L.Browser.chrome) {
            L.Browser.passiveEvents = true                                  // to better performance
        }
        const MapInfo = L.Control.extend({
            onAdd: (map) => {
                map.setZoom(26, { animate: true, duration: 2000 })
                this.panelDiv = L.DomUtil.create('newZoomDiv');
                return this.panelDiv;
            }
        });

        return new MapInfo();
    }
```